# Uk visit visa refusal under 4.2 a+c and 4.10

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

[image][image]

My visit aim to meet my sister and nephews, as they had not travel to my home last 10 years. Because my little nephew is ill and that disease 
called autism spectrum disorder (ASD). He needs his mom special care at all time.
I have also my mom in my home country she  is ill and is suffering asthma, allergy, and arthritis.
I have done my engineering degree and start my own business.
Iam the first carer of my old mom here in my home country.
I have presented that during my trip my sister( married) here in my country   will take care my mom  for some days. My father has been died.
I have submitted property detail , my car, house detail etc.
Now if i want to reappear then what steps are necessary for explaining ECO that i am a genuine visitr and come back after my trip

Comment: 1.200.000 rupies not deposited at a time. I earn this money through my shop per month basis. And deposit these funds into my acount in every month. And you know in every month you can't earn same money.

Comment: Can i reappear in this case and with what type of documents

Comment: What financial documents (over and above bank statements) for your business did you provide with your first application? See my answer below

Comment: Business registration from chamber of commerce. National tax number certificate. Confermation letter from Deputy commissioner inland revenue.

Comment: Does the Inland Revenue confirmation show the business’ turnover and profit and prove that you declared your income from the business and paid the relevant tax? Do you have separate personal and business bank accounts? UKVI will want to be able to distinguish between business trading transactions and your personal income/spending, as explained in the link in Mark Johnson’s answer.

Comment: Inland Revenue letter show my title of bussines with my name and CNIC and also confrm that i exist in their income tax records. And i dont have separate acount for business. I have a saving account and my business is in the rural area where mostly people bought their daily use thing on borrow and give us money when they get their pays and they always get the paid at start of month. So i collect  the money from them and deposit into my acount

Comment: So now kindly tell me what to do next. Can i reappear in this case and what type of extra documents are necessary for more information to satisfy ECO.

Comment: And also tell me number days as i have mentioned above 20 reduced to 10. Mean does it metter. And what about of expenses as i hve declared 500£ for 20 days in my previous application. My sponsor just help me in accommodation. I will buy all the remaining costs including air tickets my self.

Comment: Have you read the answer linked to by Mark Johnson? In particular the section headed ‘I am self-employed and do not maintain a bank account’?

Comment: Yes i read that point.

Comment: Then you have the answer. Open a separate account for your business and reapply when you can provide at least 6 months’ bank statements for your business AND you personally. Changing the number of days or the amount you plan to spend won’t make any difference in the meantime.

Comment: Just one thing. Tax return are necessary because i have registered in this year

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your refusal is probably **Funds parking**

- 1.200.000 Rupees has been deposited (for them) for no apparent reason

  - they suspect that the cause is to make your Bank statements look good for this application

You should read this answer [What Is the Purpose of Bank Statements?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/95267) carefully and try to resolve these irregularities.

Answer (score 0):

They refused on V4.2(a) and (c)

- they were not convinced your intention to visit is genuine and therefore they think you might overstay. You have family in the UK, which could make it easier to overstay and work illegally. You presented being your mother’s primary carer as a reason to return to your home country, but an ECO might ask themselves how strong this tie actually is given that you have a sister there who would be taking over this responsibility while you’re in the UK and presumably could also do so more permanently. You say you run your own business but don’t seem to have provided (sufficient) evidence as to exactly how it ties you to your home country, for example what type of business, how well-established, trading accounts, your tax returns etc.

V4.2(e) “must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds” wasn’t specifically included as a refusal reason but your financial documents demonstrated all the classic signs of ‘funds parking’, as Mark Johnson’s answer and the duplicate question explain.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules